# Set ticks margin on one axis (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

When plotting graphs with categorical variables (such as boxplots) with long names, the names have to be shifted using the `theme` command in ggplot2, then the distance between the axis ticks and the text can be set as well yet this distance is reflected on both axis when it is some time only necessary on one axis. Below some sample code:

```
df<-data.frame(X=rnorm(50,0,10),Y=c(rep("Some Text",25),rep("Some Larger Text That Takes Space",25)))

    #classical boxplots
ggplot(df,aes(x=Y,y=X))+geom_boxplot()+theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20),axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45))
    #the x axis labels need to be shifted downwards
ggplot(df,aes(x=Y,y=X))+geom_boxplot()+theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20),axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45),axis.ticks.margin=unit(4,"cm"))
    #now they are shifted but there is unnecessary space on the y-axis
```

How can we set `axis.ticks.margin` to act on only one axis?

Answer (score 2):

Try this for example :

```
  library(grid)
  axis.ticks.margin=unit(c(4,-4),'cm'))
```

So, the `ggplot2` call becomes:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Y,y=X))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45),
        axis.ticks.margin=unit(c(4,-4),'cm'))
```

Comment: Interesting. A hidden feature?

Comment: @joran I don't know why it works. I will look what happens behind the scene after.

Comment: Indeed, try passing `unit` vectors longer than two and watch the bizarre behavior that ensues. (Recycling?) The undocumented nature of this would make me at least a little nervous.

Comment: @Joran I tested that also before coming with this solution. For the moment I agree that it is a tricky solution.( work around).

Comment: @agstudy: I just found out that by using - the axis tick marks on the y axis are now on the middle of the graph which is not desirable..